# Jade - How to create table using loop with code

Tags: gulp, iteration, pug

I need create table do not coping-paste rows 
i try it :(

```
each val in ["Number", "<input type='checkbox'>", "User"]
  tr=val
```

And i was error 
**Compile by gulp-jade** 
How to paste code in to array?

Comment: What does the code look like if it was written in `HTML`?

Comment: <table>
<tr><th> Number </th>
 <th><input type='checkbox'> </th>
 <th>User</th> </tr>